# Programmatically click and move mouse with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, click, mouse, move

I want to build a program in VB .net that will allow me to control my pc with my laptop. The only question I really have is, how can I programmatically click without using some kind of click event, say if I want to click the start orb and my mouse is at that exact location, I'd like a sub or something that will click on it. Right now I only know how to click within the form.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can set the Cursor position with the property `Cursor.Position`.

You will need to [P/Invoke `mouse_event` in user32.dll](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/mouse_event.html) in order to simulate the mouse click.

Sample code in C# is here: http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=321029