# How do I invoke a mouse click in vb.net embedded browser?

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.Net form with an embedded browser and want to simulate a mouse click. Okay, this question has already been asked, **but**: I have to work with coordinates and can NOT work with elements.

The target element is a flash element which makes a difference **where** it's been clicked, not just **if** it's been clicked.

Answers so long just point to how to trigger a general click on the element. In this case, this isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

Start with [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255408/242584), and follow the links Nick provides to learn about the API calls involved. The linked example is in C#, but you can use any of the code converters on the Internet to translate it to vb.net if you like.

The below is vb.net code borrowed from an [MSDN Social post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e79d4501-b3d9-4e37-9b70-966105e09ab1/simulate-a-mouse-click-in-a-program?forum=vbgeneral). It appears to have examples of everything you would need.

```
Public Declare Auto Function SetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer) As Long
Public Declare Auto Function GetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" (ByRef lpPoint As Point) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2 ' left button down
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4 ' left button up
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = &H20 ' middle button down
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = &H40 ' middle button up
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8 ' right button down
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10 ' right button up

SetCursorPos(X,Y) ' Where X and Y are in pixel
'To get cursor location
Dim tempPos As Point
Dim R As Long = GetCursorPos(tempPos) ' You'll get your location in TempPos

'Left click
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
'Right click
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
'Middle Click
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)

'To simulate drag and drop:
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
SetCursorPos(X,Y) ' Where X and Y are in pixel
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: thanks so far, but why did you down-rate my question?

Comment: @DatLicht That wasn't me. If I had to guess, it probably had to do with the fact that you didn't post any code, or cite any resources, which generally indicates a lack of research. When posting on Stack Overflow, it is very important to show that you at least tried to *teach yourself* before asking someone to teach you.

Comment: ah okay. I already did search here (as some other users had similar, but not the same questions), but I don't understand why I should post code here from that I already know that it's useless in the moment I read it...

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much. Sometimes people can be real sticklers for the rules around here. There's even a whole [alternate website](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) where people argue about how the site works. Everybody gets down voted at some time. The 'rule of thumb' is to try to ask the most helpful questions you can. If you want to learn more, you can start with the resources [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).