# VB.NET Console Application make mouse click specific coordinates

Tags: vb.net, click, mouseevent, console-application

I am currently working in VB.Net console application. I am new to the console application, mostly working in windows forms and sql, and I am trying to write some code to make the mouse click at different spots on the screen at specific times. I have searched the web quite a bit but haven't found anything of much use. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You'll have to first [move the cursor and then make it click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255364/programmatically-click-and-move-mouse-with-vb-net).

Comment: @the_lotus So your saying I will need a way to first figure out the coordinates, for example, the first click gives a messagebox displaying coordinates so I know what I need to add to my code?

Comment: I don't quite understand. To click the mouse at a specific coordinate, you'll need to call a function to move the cursor at the specific x,y coordinate and then call a function to make a mouse click. If you are looking for a way to find the x, y coordinate you are looking for, then that's a different question.

Comment: Well, I mean it is kind of both. I will need to know the X/Y coordinate I need before the initiate the code but there seems to be a lot of information on how to do that so I will figure that out on my own. The part I cant seem to find much on is the forcing of a click somewhere on the screen.

Comment: The link I posted tell you how to get the function for GetCursorPos, SetCursorPos, mouse_event

Comment: alright im going to mess around with that link, give me some time to read through it and give it a shot